# How to combine chocolate and garlic in the same dish?

Tags: garlic, chocolate

I hosted a potluck dinner some years ago, and I set the theme as "chocolate or garlic" -- guests were to bring one or the other. One person was a wiseacre and bought chocolate covered garlic. (It was hideously unpalatable.)

I've since wondered if there's any way to combine chocolate and garlic in the same dish where you taste both, or if the two flavors are simply incompatible.

Comment: Did this have to be community wiki?  It's potentially food-science.

Comment: Sure you can put them in the same dish, just put something else between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Roasted garlic will get a slightly sweet flavor, dipped in a chocolate fondue can be wonderful and I have seen a recipe for garlic chocolate chip cookies.
http://www.food.com/recipe/garlic-chocolate-chip-cookies-28771

Comment: Definitely have to roast it.  Roasted garlic is sweet and easily palatable all by itself.  With a rich chocolate, it could be great.

Comment: Should work also with caramelized garlic, what do you think?

Answer (score 18):

Sure! Most recipes for the darker Oaxacan moles will include both cocoa powder and garlic.

Comment: I'm going to call this cheating, since there are few ingredients which _aren't_ in a good mole.  But true.

Comment: +1 for enlightening me on the existence of Oaxacan mole, now I've just got to taste some!

Answer (score 4):

Chocolate-Covered Garlic: http://www.sugoodsweets.com/blog/2007/10/chocolate-garlic/

Answer (score 3):

What about chocolate-garlic-cheesecake truffles? Four months later.. :-)

http://daydreamerdesserts.com/2011/01/chocolate-garlic-cheesecake-truffles.html/

Comment: Garlic is timeless.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to chocolate-covered *roasted* or *blanched* garlic, I've had good reviews from garlic lovers for my:

**Garlic Brownies** -- replace one egg with 4 oz. crushed garlic in oil

**Garlic Swirl Brownies** -- divide batter, 2/3 gets cocoa powder, 1/3 gets garlic

**White Chocolate Garlic Frosting** -- melt white chocolate with minced garlic